# Why is my Nikon 18-300 lens not focusing at higher focal lengths?

Tags: lens, nikon, focus, zoom

I found a similar question about the 18-200. Someone suggested screwing the front element tighter. Is it possible to do the same with the 18-300? 
My problem happens at 200-300mm.
I am not sure how to lift the outer ring around the lens and access the tabs (if they exist) to tighten it. I saw youtubes about cleaning the 18-200 but nothing for 18-300.

I also have an additional problem with the MANUAL option: at 300mm it is impossible to focus.
Thank you all in advance for your suggestions and assessments.

Comment: Please clarify: in manual focus at 300mm, you _cannot_ turn the focus ring at all? Is it grinding, or does it feel stuck, or... ? When you are zooming from ~200mm to 300mm, is there any clicking, stickiness, grinding, anything other than completely smooth movement?

Comment: Are you the only owner of this lens (did you buy it new, or used)? Has it been dropped, damaged, bumped, etc?

Comment: When you are trying to autofocus at the longer focal lengths, does it happen always? If not, what is different between those situations? Are you trying to autofocus while in poor lighting? Any details help.

Comment: Just a sanity check: you're not using it with a teleconverter, right?

Comment: Thank you all for your questions and requests for details:

Comment: SCOTTBB: new lens from a reputable company. The problem started while I was out at sea whale watching. Camera worked fine then suddenly the autofocus gave fuzzy pictures. In manual focus mode, I can turn the ring without any clicks or stops. It can turn for ever. When I try to focus, it gets closer and closer to the sweet spot but never gets crispy. If I keep turning, it gets worse. Re teleconverter: frankly I don't even know what it is. Today I tried to remove the UV filter and "tighten" the front element, but there was nothing to tighten.

Comment: @farmermarx is the problem still actual?

Answer (score -2):

additional thought - at longer extension, this lens' aperture gets smaller to the point that some bodies cannot activate the autofocus. if you aim at a well defined dark//light vertical line (say a wall corner in sunlight), does the lens focus well? if so, the issue is not the lens.

Comment: This is not correct. All Nikon DSLR bodies can autofocus at ƒ/5.6, which is the widest aperture of this lens at 300mm.